# Is the direction of sound from a piezoelectric independent of the polarity of the voltage?

Tags: acoustics, piezoelectric

My understanding is that if a patch of piezoelectric is electrified, sound pressure is emitted from both electrified sides:
[image]

If so, then isn't the emitted sound essentially the same if it's supplied by an alternating square wave or a rectified sine wave regardless of polarity?

Comment: Are you using piezoelectric material as speakers? Also by *both electrified sides* do you mean the metal plates? If yes what is the connection with the shape of the wave?

Answer (score 0):

the piezo disc produces sound waves from *both* sides when it is excited with an AC voltage. The two sets of waves are traveling in opposite directions and are 180 degrees out of phase.